# Best way to create Api Calls on Objective C using AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c

I created one class that it's handling all my API calls on some IOS APP that look like this:

```
#import "ApiManager.h"

@implementation ApiManager

- (void) initApi {

apiUrl = @"http://apiurlexample.com/";

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"grant_type": @"password",@"username": @"alamo",@"password": @"strongpass"};
[manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"alamo" password:@"strongpass"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [manager.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:[apiUrl stringByAppendingString:@"oauth"] parameters:parameters];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer alloc]];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
    apiToken = [responseObject objectForKey:@"access_token"];
    apiRefreshToken = [responseObject objectForKey:@"refresh_token"];
    apiTokenType = [responseObject objectForKey:@"token_type"];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
}];
[manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];

}

- (User *) ifAutenticacaoLogin:(Login *)login;
{
User *user = [[User alloc] init];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", apiTokenType, apiToken]);
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", apiTokenType, apiToken] ] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[manager POST:[apiUrl stringByAppendingString:@"api/IFAutenticacao/login"] parameters:login success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

return user;
}

@end
```

and i'm calling this way:

```
apiManager = [[ApiManager alloc] init];
[apiManager initApi];

Login *login = [[Login alloc] init];
login.email = @"user@mail.com.br";
login.senha = @"password";

User *user = [[User alloc] init];
user = [apiManager ifAutenticacaoLogin:login];
```

the problem it's, that the second call need to wait the first complete, because the token come's from **init**.

```
apiToken = [responseObject objectForKey:@"access_token"];
apiRefreshToken = [responseObject objectForKey:@"refresh_token"];
apiTokenType = [responseObject objectForKey:@"token_type"];
```

what's the best way to do that? put a timer?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to asynchronous requests delay is probably the worst you can do when sometimes you got slow internet connection on your phone. Doing it in the loop is the second worst. There is a beautiful thing called **blocks** in objective-c and its doing wonders in this case. You can use **completion blocks** to verify if your method is completed correctly. Very basic example of API with completion blocks (added to your methods, I've used BOOLs but you can also get the response as a NSDictionary etc.).

API method:

```
- (void) initApiWithCompletionBlock:(void(^)(BOOL completed))completion {
    apiUrl = @"http://apiurlexample.com/";

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"grant_type": @"password",@"username": @"alamo",@"password": @"strongpass"};
    [manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"alamo" password:@"strongpass"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [manager.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:[apiUrl stringByAppendingString:@"oauth"] parameters:parameters];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer alloc]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
        apiToken = [responseObject objectForKey:@"access_token"];
        apiRefreshToken = [responseObject objectForKey:@"refresh_token"];
        apiTokenType = [responseObject objectForKey:@"token_type"];
        completion(YES);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
        completion(NO);
    }];
    [manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
}
```

Calling the method:

```
apiManager = [[ApiManager alloc] init];
[apiManager initApiWithCompletionBlock:^(BOOL completed) {
    if(completed) {
        Login *login = [[Login alloc] init];
        login.email = @"user@mail.com.br";
        login.senha = @"password";
        User *user = [[User alloc] init];
        user = [apiManager ifAutenticacaoLogin:login];
    }
}];
```

And so on..